# ESB WSO2: I want to insert data into a database through a data service I created but I get this error

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

This is the error I get in the console:

```
[2022-02-17 08:55:40,121] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} - The system cannot infer the transport information from the nio-local://services/my_first_project_data-services URL.
[2022-02-17 08:55:40,122]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} - Endpoint : ep.insertUserAddress with address nio-local://services/my_first_project_data-services will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2022-02-17 08:55:40,123]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} - Suspending endpoint : ep.insertUserAddress with address nio-local://services/my_first_project_data-services - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Thu Feb 17 08:56:10 EET 2022
[2022-02-17 08:55:40,125]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.PassThroughTransportUtils} - Unable to set the HTTP status code from the property HTTP_SC with value:
```

This is my API source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/api/dbtask/insert" name="api.dbtask.insert" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <call blocking="true">
                <endpoint key="ep.insertUserAddress"/>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

This is my endpoint source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="ep.insertUserAddress" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address uri="nio-local://services/my_first_project_data-services">
        <suspendOnFailure>
            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
        </markForSuspension>
    </address>
</endpoint>
```

This is my dataservice source code:

```
<data name="my_first_project_data-services" serviceNamespace="" serviceGroup="" transports="http https">
    <description/>
        <config id="default">
            <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.protocol">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/utilizatori</property>
            <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">root</property>
            <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">1234</property>
        </config>
        
        <operation name="insertUser" returnRequestStatus="true">
            <call-query href="insertUser"/>
        </operation>
        
        <query id="insertUser" useConfig="default">
            <sql>INSERT INTO utilizatori.users (id, nume, varsta) VALUES (14, "Alexandru", 50)</sql>
        </query>    
</data>
```

The thing is when I'm trying the service here, it works:
[image]
I'm using Postman to send requests

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the data service URL you have configured "**nio-local://services/my_first_project_data-services**". The format of the data service endpoint should look like follows [1].

```
http://localhost:8280/services/RDBMSDataService/employee
```

But if your intention is to use the local transport, you first need to enable the local transport. You can find more information on this in the blog post [2].

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Exposing+a+Datasource+as+a+Data+Service

[2]-https://mcvidanagama.medium.com/install-dss-features-to-esb-and-enable-local-transport-for-data-service-endpoints-f4866495a8d7